# Primes of the form $a^n-(a-1)^n$

Tags: prime-numbers

For a given $n$, consider the assertion:

$\exists a \in \Bbb Z : a^n-(a-1)^n\ \text{is prime}\tag*{}$

How can one do one of the following:

- Prove that the assertion is true for all integer $n > 1$
- Prove that the assertion is false for all integer $n > 1$
- Characterize the values of $n > 1$ for which the assertion is true

The assertion is clearly true (with $a=2$) for all values of $n$ that are Mersenne prime exponents. Also, we only need to consider positive values for $a$. If $a<0$ then $a^n-(a-1)^n$ is negative (and hence not prime) when $n$ is even and is equal to $(1-a)^n-((1-a)-1)^n$ when $n$ is odd.

<strike>I suspect the assertion is true for all $n > 1$, but I have no idea how to prove it.</strike>

EDIT (thanks to @Malcolm):

The assertion is false whenever $n$ is composite. This is because $a^{uv} - (a-1)^{uv}$ is divisible by $a^u - (a-1)^u$ and by $a^v - (a-1)^v$. (This can be shown by induction on $v$ for $a^u - (a-1)^u$ and vice versa.)

I'd still like to know if the assertion is true for $n$ prime and not a Mersenne prime exponent.

EDIT 2:

It turns out that this family of numbers has been studied before, although not extensively, as one form of generalized Mersenne numbers. (See, for instance, the 2003 conference paper [*Generalized Mersenne prime numbers: characterization and distributions*](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/digest2003/papers/459-160.pdf) by Vladimir Pletser.) It also turns out that there are indeed primes of the form $a^n - (a-1)^n$ for values of $n$ that are not Mersenne prime exponents. For instance,

$M_{11} = 2^{11} - 1 = 2047 = 23\cdot89\tag*{}$

while

$6^{11} - 5^{11} = 313968931\tag*{}$

is prime. Pletser established by brute force that there are primes of the form $a^n - (a-1)^n$ for all prime $n$ through 31. He and T. D. Noe have tabulated the smallest such prime for the first 80 primes. See [OEIS A121620](https://oeis.org/A121620).

Comment: To get you started, observe that for $n=2,3$ the value $a=2$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: @pwerth - Right. However, I'm not particularly interesting in specific values of $n$. The assertion is obviously true (with $a=2$) for all exponents corresponding to Mersenne primes. I suspect that the assertion is true for all $n>1$, but I have no idea how to prove that.

Comment: I only wrote that comment because your question does not indicate that you had evaluated any base cases or even knew that it was true or false for a given $n$. I suggest rewording your question to include basically what you just wrote in that comment.

Comment: @pwerth - Fair enough. I've updated the question.

Comment: The assertion fails for $n=4$ and for $n=6$ as $a^4 - (a-1)^4 = (2a-1)(2a^2-2a+1)$ and $a^6 - (a-1)^6 = (2a-1)(3a^2-3a+1)(a^2-a+1)$

Comment: @Malcolm - Thanks for that. I wonder if it fails for all composite $n$.

Comment: @TedHopp I think it might.  This may be related to factoring of cyclotomic polynomials, but it is a long time ago that I last looked at that.

Comment: @Malcolm - It turns out that it's easy to prove that $a^{uv} - (a-1)^{uv}$ has factors $a^u-(a-1)^u$ and $a^v - (a-1)^v$.

Comment: A step in the right direction would be to show $x^p-(x-1)^p$ is an irreducible polynomial for $p$ prime.

Comment: If you can show a polynomial is irreducible, then under some other mild conditions, there is a conjecture that it achieves prime values infinitely many times.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture